# Split files using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

This is my first time posting a question, so please bear with me for any errors.
I am trying to Split the numeric values with a delimiter of ';' using sql into separate columns, i was able to achieve splitting part of it using the code below but i will like to split the rest of it within column 3 to separate columns
I have a table like this

```
ID    catalogNumber    STEPID1
----------------------------
815326  FBRS415    499023;499027;726203
```

```
with tmp(catalognumber,stepid1_split,stepid1) as (
select catalognumber,cast(LEFT(stepid1, CHARINDEX(';',stepid1+';')-1) as varchar),cast(STUFF(stepid1, 1, CHARINDEX(';',stepid1+';'), '') as varchar)
from EXACT_MATCH
union all
select catalognumber, cast(LEFT(stepid1, CHARINDEX(';',stepid1+';')-1) as varchar), cast(STUFF(stepid1, 1, CHARINDEX(';',stepid1+';'), '') as varchar)
from tmp
where stepid1> ''
)
select *
from tmp
```

```
ID     catalogNumber    STEPID1    STEPID2    STEPID3
---------------------------------------------------
815326   FBRS415         499023      499027      726203
```

Comment: Sql server 2014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that, you could try `XML`.. `.node()` method to split your comma values into individual columns note that this will always gives you three columns.

You will need to add some extra columns in order to display comma separated values as you define

```
select distinct 
       a.ID,
       a.catalogNumber,
       c.value('/m[1]', 'varchar(max)') [STEPID1],
       c.value('/m[2]', 'varchar(max)') [STEPID2],
       c.value('/m[3]', 'varchar(max)') [STEPID3] from 
(
    select ID ,   catalogNumber ,   cast('<m>'+replace(STEPID1, ';', '</m><m>')+'</m>' as xml) [STEPID1]  from <table>
) a cross apply STEPID1.nodes ('/m') as STEPID1(c)
```

Result :

```
ID      catalogNumber   STEPID1  STEPID2  STEPID3
815326  FBRS415         499023   499027   726203
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you for all your help, I am very Grateful